# Promoting the Spanish-language SE proposals

Tags: discusión

One way we can help promote this site, in the long-term, is by promoting and participating in the other Spanish-speaking proposals on Area 51.  I encourage everyone on this site, who feels they could contribute meaningfully to one of the other proposals, to follow and/or commit.

The two other Spanish-language proposals are:

- [Stack Overflow (in Spanish)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish?referrer=i2UNs-26fec9zlsUrCq6xg2)
- [Superuser (in Spanish)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42327/superuser-in-spanish?referrer=i2UNs-26feccVcWANpeLkQ2)

If either or both of these sites ever go live, I'm sure it will greatly help cross-polinate this site.  In the mean time, participating in the proposals will also help draw attention of Spanish-speakers to the SE network in general, which can also help this site grow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to see if there's anything I can contribute to Stackoverflow in Spanish.

I don't know computer technology from A to Z, but I do contribute to one fairly narrow area that Stackoverflow covers.  It's database design.  Back in the 1980s, I taught one or two week courses on database design and development for what was, at the time, the second largest computer maker in the world.

And I know a few concepts that are still relevant, and I know them well enough to post answers that are generally well recieved.

Almost half of the database courses I taught were in Spanish,  in Mexico and Puerto Rico.  My conversational Spanish is good enough so that my presentation was easier to follow than the presentation given in English.

So I might be able to help with one small aspect of getting SO in Spanish off the ground.  I'm not an expert on forums, communities, or websites, but I've been around for a while.

---

Went there, and made a comment about my interest.  We'll see what happens.  The original proposal was closed for lack of progress, but there's an effort to start a new one.

Comment: I posted my interest in the wrong place, and my post got deleted. After that, I managed to get myself included as a "follower" of the proposed new Spanish SO. It looks like the effort is under way again, but is not gathering enough momentum. They still need more good questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm involved in the [StackOverflow in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish?referrer=UCvpq888Myc9zlsUrCq6xg2) proposal.  This is the first time I came to this post here, but we are thinking the same.

This Monday I published a post in my blog: [El idioma español y su uso](http://jachguate.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/el-idioma-espanol-y-su-uso/) to get some attention from the people following me and the es.StackOverflow proposal to the SL&U site, hoping to bring here more users helping this beta to get better numbers, but at the same time wanting to allow the people new to the StackExchange network to learn by experience with a live site before the es.StackOverflow goes to beta.

I think this is correct, but please let me know here in comments if there's anything wrong with it.